# BigInteger in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, biginteger

How would I be able to get a "BigInteger" class for use in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What revision of Silverlight?

It doesn't exist pre Silverlight 4, but have a look in System.Numerics if you are running SL4.

(System.Numerics.BigInterger : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.95%29.aspx)